# python marshmallow: any workaround to validate nested request JSON?

Tags: python, json, validation, marshmallow

I want to validate nested request JSON with `marshmallow`, I pretty much followed its documentation to validate my request JSON data. After I several attempts, I think using marshmallow to validate complex JSON data is right way. However, I got a validation error from marshmallow as follow:

**updated error message**

```
> PS C:\Users\jyson\immunomatch_api> python .\json_validation.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File ".\json_validation.py", line
> 58, in <module>
>     app = schema.load(app_data)   File "C:\Users\jyson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\marshmallow\schema.py",
> line 723, in load  
>     data, many=many, partial=partial, unknown=unknown, postprocess=True   File
> "C:\Users\jyson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\marshmallow\schema.py",
> line 904, in _do_load
>     raise exc marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'_schema': ['Invalid input type.']}
```

**update**

before I got positional argument error because I implicitly define features like `def __init__(self, age, gender, features)` instead of doing hard code in def **init**(self, age, gender, IL10, CRP). why I have above error? any quick thought? thanks

**my attempt for json validation with marshmallow**:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_load
from marshmallow import EXCLUDE
import json

class Feature(object):
    def __init__(self, value, device):
        self.value = value
        self.device= device

class FeatureSchema(Schema):
    value = fields.Str()
    device= fields.Str()

    @post_load
    def make_feature(self, data, **kwargs):
        return Feature(**data)

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, age, gender, features):
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
        self.features = features

class AppSchema(Schema):
    age = fields.Str()
    gender = fields.Str()
    features = fields.Nested(FeatureSchema)

    @post_load
    def make_app(self, data, **kwargs):
        return App(**data)

json_data = """{

"body": {
    "gender": "M",
    "PCT4": {
      "value": 12,
      "device": "roche_cobas"
    },
    "IL10": {
      "value": 12,
      "device": "roche_cobas"
    },
    "CRP": {
      "value": 12,
      "device": "roche_cobas"
    },
     "OM10": {
      "value": 120,
      "device": "roche_bathes"
    }
  }
}"""

app_data = json.loads(json_data)

schema = AppSchema(unknown=EXCLUDE, many=TRUE)
app = schema.load(app_data)

print(app.data.features.value)
```

why I have the above error? what's the right way to validate nested JSON? why I am having unknown field error? any possible thought to get rid of error above? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly mentions the issue

```
marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError: {'OM10': ['Unknown field.'], 'CRP': ['Unknown field.'], 'IL10': ['Unknown field.'], 'PCT4': ['Unknown field.']}
```

Marshmallow's Schema doesn't understand the field, since you have not declared it into your schema, and by default, Marshmallow will raise an error if it finds an `Unknown Field`

An easy fix is to `EXCLUDE` them as looking at your code, it seems you dont need it anyway.

I would suggest passing in `unknown` argument as `EXCLUDE` when instantiating it.

```
from marshmallow import EXCLUDE
schema = AppSchema(unknown=EXCLUDE)
```

More information can be found here - https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#handling-unknown-fields

Comment: thanks for the heads up. but after I tried your input, I had this error: `TypeError: make_app() got an unexpected keyword argument 'many' `, but I fixed that by adding **kwargs. Now I have this: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'features' `;  any further thought? I pasted the new error message above

Comment: I have a positional argument because I have to explicitly define an object like `PCT4`, `IL10` instead of an abstract objects like `featuers`. How can I make it work? I updated the error message above. thanks

Comment: This doesnt work because you dont have `features` in the json. You need to define the same structure like you have it in json. 
I would suggest you change `AppSchema` and add `PCT4` `CRP`` etc in it as nested fields

Comment: after validation, how can I serialize back `app = schema.load(app_data)` to json string like `json.dumps(app)` ? I am gonna accpt your solution. thanks

Comment: Yes thats the way to do it